# my system function executes the passed string separately

Tags: c, bash, c-strings

I was trying to pass a string to another string to execute a `system()` command, but it executes the string separately
"sudo ifconfig %s" then "down". I hope someone can explain me what is happening.

Code:

```
int main() 
{
    char wlanint[200];
    char ifconfig[3200];

    system("clear");
    printf("\n");
    printf("Here are your wlan interfaces:\n\n");
    system("iw dev | awk '$1==\"Interface\"{print $2}'");
    printf("\n\nWlan interface to change the mac: ");

    fgets(wlanint, 200, stdin);

    snprintf(ifconfig, 3200, "sudo ifconfig %s down",wlanint);
    system(ifconfig);

    getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

The output:

```
Here are your wlan interfaces:

wlx7cdd90f63905


Wlan interface to select: wlx7cdd90f63905
wlx7cdd90f63905: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.9  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        ether 3a:d1:3a:86:1b:a5  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 151033  bytes 153673265 (153.6 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 7047855  bytes 447465001 (447.4 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

sh: 2: down: not found
```

Comment: `fgets()` transfers the input line's trailing newline to the provided buffer.  You are copying that forward to the next command, and the shell interprets it as a line separator.

Comment: Overall, though, it looks like you really want to be writing a shell script.  C is a very awkward way to go about that.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I was actually trying to add this code into a bigger pile of code for something else written in C. That's why I am using C to run that bash command. Well, including a bash file just for this didn't seemed like a great idea to me. Nevertheless would you recommend me to include a bash file instead of giving this effort.

Comment: I probably wouldn't embed a bash script into a larger C project.  I *would* give strong consideration to providing an external helper script that the program would execute via `system()`.  But ultimately, I do not know nearly enough about the scope, nature, and requirements of your larger project to give a firm recommendation.